# Dynamic Partition Value SQL Server Azure Synapse

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, partition, azure-synapse

How can I set the Table with dynamic partition ? is it possible to do it on Azure Synapse?

This is my script

```
CREATE TABLE dashboard_table WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH(product_id), 
    PARTITION (partition_key RANGE RIGHT FOR 
        VALUES (20200101,20200102,20200103,20200104,20200105,20200106) AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM table_x
        )
```

Because when I try to create a partition by this example script it doesnt work on synapse

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION myRangePF1 (int) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 100, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools (and Azure SQL Data Warehouse before it) do not support the `CREATE PARTITION SCHEME` or `FUNCTION` commands.  Instead build the partition definition into your `CREATE TABLE` as in your first example.  If you want to do this dynamically you will need to use dynamic SQL.  This is the example from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition#syntax-differences-from-sql-server):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
    [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
,   [OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
,   [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
,   [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
,   [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
,   [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL
)
WITH
(   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
,   DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ProductKey])
,   PARTITION   (   [OrderDateKey] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
                    (20000101,20010101,20020101
                    ,20030101,20040101,20050101
                    )
                )
);
```

I notice you are partitioning by day.  Just remember less is more with Synapse partitioning.  You need at least 1 million rows per distribution (ie 60 million) for it to become effective.  See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition#sizing-partitions) for notes on partition sizing:

> When creating partitions on clustered columnstore tables, it is
> important to consider how many rows belong to each partition. For
> optimal compression and performance of clustered columnstore tables, a
> **minimum of 1 million rows** per distribution and partition is needed.
> Before partitions are created, dedicated SQL pool already divides each
> table into 60 distributed databases.
>
> Any partitioning added to a table is in addition to the distributions
> created behind the scenes. Using this example, if the sales fact table
> contained 36 monthly partitions, and given that a dedicated SQL pool
> has 60 distributions, then the sales fact table should contain 60
> million rows per month, or 2.1 billion rows when all months are
> populated. If a table contains fewer than the recommended minimum
> number of rows per partition, consider using fewer partitions in order
> to increase the number of rows per partition.

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask, is it possible to create a dynamic partition value for this ? Let say I want to set the partition value with range from variable SET like start_date or end_date

Comment: Does this apply also to `AzureSql` database?